# Verificar se string digitada está em formato de e-mail

Tags: c, string

Galera, preciso de uma ajuda para verificar se o e-mail digitado termina em "@usp.br".

Eis o código que já tentei:

```
/* pega o tamanho total do email digitado */
int tamanho = strlen(email);
/* a partir do tamanho do email, comece a contar nos ultimos 7 caracteres -> que deve terminar em "@usp.br" */
int ultimos = email[tamanho-7]; /* -> se o email tiver 20 caracteres, comece do indice 13 */

char verifica[7] = "@usp.br";
int k=0;

for(i=0; i < 7; i++){
    /* exemplo */
    /* comece a comparar no indice 13, que deve conter a letra "@" */
    if(email[tamanho-7] == verifica[k]){
        k++;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        printf("Email digitado incorreto! Digite um email que termine com '@usp.br'!");
    }
    //k++;
}
```

Comment: Este código não faz sentido e duvido que faça nem mesmo perto do que pretende. De qualquer forma, não vi uma dúvida aí, só um pedido de ajuda que não está no escopo do site. Tenta melhorar isso pra podermos ajudar.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil fazer `if (strcmp(email+(strlen(email)-7), "@usp.br") == 0)` ? Garantindo que tem pelo menos 7 caracteres claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz desse jeito:

```
int emailusp(const char *email) {

    /* Pega o tamanho total do e-mail digitado. */
    int tamanho = strlen(email);

    /* Se for muito curto, cai fora retornando 0. */
    if (tamanho < 7) return 0;

    const char verifica[7] = "@usp.br";

    /* Verifica se cada um dos últimos caracteres é "@usp.br". Se encontrar um que não é, retorna 0. */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (email[tamanho - 7 + i] != verifica[i]) return 0;
    }

    /* Os os últimos caracteres são "@usp.br". Retorna 1. */
    return 1;
}

void testar(const char *email) {
    int valido = emailusp(email);
    printf("%s%s eh um e-mail da USP.\n", email, valido ? "" : " nao");
}

int main() {
   testar("verde@usp.br");
   testar("azul@usp.br");
   testar("amarelo@gmail.com");
   testar("vermelho@upp.br");
   testar("a@a");
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
verde@usp.br eh um e-mail da USP.
azul@usp.br eh um e-mail da USP.
amarelo@gmail.com nao eh um e-mail da USP.
vermelho@upp.br nao eh um e-mail da USP.
a@a nao eh um e-mail da USP.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ovvNeL)

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor, foi muito útil.